# Cancel a file upload in fineuploader jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader with the the jquery wrapper and would like to cancel/destroy an instance when a certain event happens. Basically the uploader exists in a boostrap modal and when the modal is closed I would like to stop any uploading because it seems to break the browser if I dont and then later try again.

I see the onCancel callback but I do not see a way to call a cancel event or basically destroy the fineuploader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't access "private" functions/properties.  These may change or disappear at any time.  I added a [`cancelAll` API function in 3.3](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/428).  You can use that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick

```
$('selector').data('fineuploader').uploader._handler.cancelAll();
```